# Cancel ajax calls?

Tags: ajax, django, jquery-select2

I'm using the [Select2](https://select2.github.io/) select boxes in my Django project. The ajax calls it makes can be fairly time-consuming if you've only entered a character or two in the query box, but go quicker if you've entered several characters. So what I'm seeing is you'll start typing a query, and it will make 4 or 5 ajax calls, but the final one returns and the results display. It looks fine on the screen, but meanwhile, the server is still churning away on the earlier queries. I've increased the "delay" parameter to 500 ms, but it's still a bit of a problem.

Is there a way to have the AJAX handler on the server detect that this is a new request from the same client as one that is currently processing, and tell the older one to exit immediately? It appears from reading other answers here that merely calling `.abort()` on the client side doesn't stop the query running on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are DB queries that are taking up time, then basically nothing will stop them besides stopping the database server, which is of course not tangible. If it is computation in nested loops for example, then you could use cache to detect whether another request has been submitted from the same user. Basically:

```
from django.core.cache import cache    

def view(request):
    start_time = timestamp # timezone.now() etc.
    cache.set(request.session.session_key + 'some_identifier', start_time)
    for q in werty:
        # Very expensive computation with millions of loops
        if start_time != cache.get(request.session.session_key + 'some_identifier'):
            break
        else:
            # Continue the nasty computations
    else:
        cache.delete(request.session.session_key + 'some_identifier')
```

But the Django part aside - what I would do: in JS add a condition that when the search word is less than 3 chars, then it waits 0.5s (or less, whatever you like) before searching. And if another char is added then search right away.
I.e.

```
var timeout;

function srch(param) {
    timeout = false;
    if (param.length < 3) {
        timeout = true;
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (timeout) {
                $.ajax({blah: blah});
            }
        }, 500);
    } else {
        $.ajax({blah: blah});
    }
}
```

Comment: What, what actually sets the value in the cache?

Comment: @PaulTomblin Oops, updated the answer. It was meant to be random pseudo code anyway to start your thoughts, but something of that sort should actually work as well.